# Freeze when playing video 17.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, freeze

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10 but I get random freezes when watching videos, YouTube or even in Vlc. I disabled hardware acceleration and installed Linux Intel gpu graphics (I have an i7 and 8GB ram) my computer is an Acer aspire E15 E5-575-33BM The problem is occurring in both Xorg and Wayland

I'd like some help to solve this really annoying problem

```
free
total used free shared buff/cache available 
Mem: 8033204 2450468 2635076 466488 2947660 4947820 
Swap: 2097148 0 2097148

swapon --show
NAME TYPE SIZE USED PRIO 
/swapfile file 2G 0B -1
```

Comment: Do you have `swap` space defined? How much? `free;swapon show`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do a clean comment formatting here is the result of free : total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available  
Mem:        8033204     2450468     2635076      466488     2947660     4947820
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148

Comment: And here is the result of swapon --show : NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G   0B   -1

Comment: @https://askubuntu.com/users/802565/baptiste-knacky you can Edit your initial question and add the information there, with formatting.

Comment: 1. Close other tasks. Run `gnome-system-monitor`. 2. Try downloading a video, then playing it. If problem doesn't happen, suspect network problems.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, my Ubuntu system freezes, forcing me to manually shutdown the laptop